# Unable to build release APK when using ProGuard

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I have an Android project created in Eclipse with ADT bundle. I want to export a release APK using ProGuard but keep getting errors.

I know this has to do with the Google Play Services library because when I remove it from the project it exports the APK successfully.

The project.properties looks like this:

```
proguard.config=proguard-android.cfg
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib
```

The proguard-android.cfg looks like this:

```
-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-printmapping proguard-android.map
-dontwarn
-dontoptimize
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

I have added the keep class definition because when I run it I get the following errors:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console.

[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp] Note: there were 1030 duplicate class definitions.
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp]   Class       = [com/google/android/gms/d/f]
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp]   Method      = [a(ILandroid/app/Activity;Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z]
[2019-10-09 06:34:32 - AndroidApp]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [com/google/android/gms/d/g] (not even immediate super class [android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment]))
```

Can anyone give me any help as to what the errors mean and how to get it working?